# При наведении на ссылку скачет текст

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Сделал так, чтобы при наведении на ссылку, снизу появлялось подчеркивание. Но почему-то текст скачет при наведении. В чем причина ?

```css
body{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-nav li{
 margin-left: 35px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

header .nav-item a {
 color: #6c6c6c;
}

header .nav-item a:hover {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #5094f2;

}

.navbar-toggler{
 background-color: #5094f2;
}

.fa-bars{
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Prechu</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome-free-5.9.0-web/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <header class="header" id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Потому что изначальный бордер равен 0, а при наведении вы изменяете его ширину, вот и скачет. Можете добавить такой стиль: `header .nav-item a { border-bottom: 3px solid transparent; }`

Comment: @entithat Добавил, перестало скакать . Спасибо! Так всегда надо будет прописывать, если хочу сделать полосу снизу при наведении ?

Comment: В зависимости от ситуации конечно. Возможно да, возможно и нет

Comment: @entithat оно получается скачет,потому что расширяется блок ссылки ?

Comment: Грубо говоря - да

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы текст не прыгал, добавьте ссылке изначально нижнюю рамку, но сделайте её прозрачной.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-nav li {
  margin-left: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header .nav-item a {
  color: #6c6c6c;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

header .nav-item a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #5094f2;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  background-color: #5094f2;
}

.fa-bars {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Prechu</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome-free-5.9.0-web/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <header class="header" id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
            </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

  </html>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Текст скачет по причине border-bottom: 3px solid #5094f2; по ховеру. Хочешь что б не скакал пиши, так

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-nav li {
  margin-left: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header .nav-item a {
  color: #6c6c6c;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}

header .nav-item a:hover {
  border-color: #5094f2;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  background-color: #5094f2;
}

.fa-bars {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome-free-5.9.0-web/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

<header class="header" id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
          </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Таким образом ты не меняешь размер блока с ссылкой по наведению, а только его цвет